# Reload page after Update cart button clicked(on cart page) Woocommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Can somebody please help me with writing hook or jQuery code to reload cart page when update button is clicked and update triggered ?
Woo-commerce is plugin!

Comment: Why do you need this? Please edit your answer to elaborate. Also, consider adding your research and what you've tried and explain why that isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: @helgatheviking Here is the thing : i am repairing some theme which previously made bad developer. On cart page i have for every cart product quantity button and button update cart. When i first time load cart page, and change quantities for products and click Update cart, i see its updated via Ajax. After that first updating action quantities buttons are not working. plus and minus are not inc/dec values in field anymore. Then i realized that when i reload cart page in browser it is working again. I know it is not maybe elegant solution but i just want to do reloading.

Comment: I sympathize with trying to repair a bad theme. I've done it before myself. Instead of trying to figure out what has gone wrong with the theme and using this as a bandaid, I'd suggest just deleting your theme's template overrides and using the default WC template. Maybe removing any of the theme's custom code/script concerning the cart too. Go back to default and then only add back the bare minimum.

Comment: If you need plus/minus buttons, I posted a [gist](https://gist.github.com/helgatheviking/6abe7385c23ba4238710ba6d1ccc5181) that may be helpful a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

If the update functionality is custom and not the woocommerce default, what may be happening is the javascript functionality to trigger the ajax on the button press is bound to that event initially, however when the elements are reloaded through the ajax, the event is not bound to those new elements.

By default woocommerce triggers two events when it updates the cart through ajax, updated_wc_div, and updated_cart_totals. You could bind a function to either of these events to reload the page, like this:

```
jQuery( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function() {
    // code to reload page here
});
```

However in my personal opinion this is not the best way. If the customizations have completely messed up the default cart functionality of woocommerce (which appears to be the case here). It would be best to fix them to restore the default functionality, or if that is not possible to start with the default templates and rebuild the customizations from there (in a way that doesn't interfere with core functionality).

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a error in your template. The older versions of woocommerce reloaded the cart after the update. But in newer versions there is a ajax action bound to that. This action blocks the default form action and fire the ajax.

Probably the script blocks your form but the ajax action fails ... do you use a standard theme or a custom one?

Try update themes and plugins.